# Uninstalling Python 3.10 and Installing Python 3.9 on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos-big-sur, python-3.9, python-3.10

I really need help with the following problem. I am trying to figure out how to go about uninstalling Python 3.10.1 on my computer which is a Mac OS Big Sur laptop (Version 11.6.2). I would like to install Python 3.9 instead.

I go to the terminal on my computer and try to type the following command to uninstall Python 3.10:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

I hit enter after this command and the following shows up on my terminal screen:

```
Password: Key icon
```

It is at this point that I am totally unsure of what to do.

Comment: Just type in your password into the terminal and hit enter after you finished, it's normal that the terminal won't show your password and it's like nothing has happened